# Excel VBA - Find a set of characters and set as string

Tags: search, excel, find, vba

I have a set of descriptions that contain ID numbers arranged into a column. For example:

**Column A**

This is a description with the ID number in it ID12345.

This is a description ID66666 with the ID number in it.

This is ID99999 a description with  the ID number in it.

The Id numbers are always in the format "IDXXXXX" I'd like to somehow trim away all the text in each of these cells and leave just that ID number.

My thoughts: 
Can this be somehow done by finding a string like "ID?????" and setting that to a variable, then replacing the contents of the cell with that variable? Or by erasing all characters in a cell -except- for "ID?????"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use regular expressions to get the numbers which follows the ID.

Comment: Any chance of an example or a resource I could use on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code I wrote for you will iterate through all items in Column A. It will split all the words in each cell into an array. If the word is 7 or 8 characters long then it could potentially be an `IDxxxxx`. It will perform a few checks to see if it really matches an `IDxxxxx` syntax. In case it does it will replace the contents of the cell with just the ID dropping all the remaining text.

```
Sub ReplaceContentWithIDs()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' or your sheet name
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i&, lr&, j&
    Dim arr
    Dim str$

    lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' starting from 1 - if you have headers change to 2
    For i = 1 To lr
        Set rng = ws.Range("A" & i)
        arr = Split(CStr(rng.Value), " ")
        For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            str = arr(j)
            If (Len(str) = 7) Or (Len(str) = 8) Then
                If (StrComp(Left(str, 2), "ID", vbTextCompare) = 0) And _
                IsNumeric(Right(Left(str, 7), 5)) Then
                    ' found it
                    If Len(str) = 8 Then
                        rng.Value = Left(str, 7)
                    ElseIf Len(str) = 7 Then
                        rng.Value = str
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        Set rng = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I took this as a challenge to my intellect, and given that it is the end of the day, after seeing the formulas by [Aladdin](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/411222-formula-help-how-represent-numeric-wildcard.html#post2037191) and [pgc01](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/411222-formula-help-how-represent-numeric-wildcard-2.html#post2037800) on Mr Excel forums I did a little work and came up with this CSE (Array formula):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,SEARCH({"ID0","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6","ID7","ID8","ID9"},A1))),MID(A1,LOOKUP(9.99999999999999E+307,SEARCH({"ID0","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6","ID7","ID8","ID9"},A1)),7),"")
```

I also had some luck with this CSE Array formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ID"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A$1)),MID(A$1,SEARCH("ID"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A$1),7))
```

Comment: Nice effort. However the formulas dont work with the case of a `.` (`dot`) at the end of the `IDxxxxx.` Also, the op wanted to just replace the content of the cell - which he could do by deleting column A if the formula was in the column B so not a major thing

Comment: yeah they definitely need a little tweaking (such as including a `Substitute` function perhaps for other characters), along with much gnashing of teeth and several cigarette breaks :)

Comment: next I might take a look at a possible **Regular Expression** solution, but that's for another day...